# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.util.SparseBooleanArray.get(int)' on a null object reference

Tags: android

I am creating an alert dialog that has some checkedtextviews and I want to take only the checked ones and add them through my Service class to my activity.

Whenever I try to tun it it works fine until I click the ok in the dialog box. I get the following:

Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.util.SparseBooleanArray.get(int)' on a null object reference

```
public class DisplayShoppingListDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    private ShoppingList list;
    private AlertDialog alert;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //defines the activity layout
        setContentView(R.layout.shopping_list_details);

        ListView listViewDetails = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.shopping_list_details);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        list = (ShoppingList) intent.getSerializableExtra("ShoppingList");

        ProductsOnListAdapter ad = new ProductsOnListAdapter(this, -1, Service.getService().getProductsOnList(list));
        listViewDetails.setAdapter(ad);

        FloatingActionButton button = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.floatingButton);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                createDialog(list);
    }

    private void createDialog(final ShoppingList list){
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(DisplayShoppingListDetailsActivity.this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_of_products, null);

        final ListView listView = (ListView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.list_of_products_listView);
        ListOfProductsAdapter adapter = new ListOfProductsAdapter(this, -1, Service.getService().getPromotions());
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok_button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                ArrayList<String> checkedItems = new ArrayList<>();
                SparseBooleanArray checked = listView.getCheckedItemPositions();
                for (int i = 0; i <listView.getAdapter().getCount(); i++) {
                    if (checked.get(i)) {
                        String item = String.valueOf(listView.getItemIdAtPosition(checked.keyAt(i)));
                        //checkedItems.add(item);
                        Service.getService().updateProductToList(list, item);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel_button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            }
        });

        builder.setView(dialogView);
        alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you have set the right choice mode to your `ListView`.

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#getCheckedItemPositions()
>
> SparseBooleanArray which will return true for each call to get(int position) where position is a checked position in the list and false otherwise, or **null if the choice mode is set to CHOICE_MODE_NONE.**